# Changing my shell bash script default $PWD to it's (the script's) current location

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pwd

Hey I'm running my shell script that interacts with folders and files, but my $PWD that it keeps pointing to /home/MyUserName directory and this messes with what it is supposed to do. I am running Linux 4.4.8-300.fc23.x86_64 GNU/Linux:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash -x

clear
ls $PWD

#Check Root
echo checking Root user
if [ $EUID -ne 0 ]
then
    sudo su
fi;

#Check internet availablity
TEST=$(ping -c 1 74.125.21.14|wc -l)
if [ $TEST -gt 5 2>&1 ]
then
    sudo dnf install gcc kernel-devel binutils cpp glibc-devel glibc-headers isl kernel kernel-headers libmpc
else
    echo "No Internet Connection Available! Installing RPMs manuely."
    arr=(*.rpm)
    for (( i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i++ ));
    do
        echo " ${arr[$i]} "
        dnf -y install ${arr[$i]}
    done
fi;

# Get Network Ability

echo "Starting the setup of your laptop's wireless card."
if [ -d ./MyWirelessCard ]
then
    FILE=./MyWirelessCard/fedora23_broadcom_wl_install.sh
    uname1=" $( stat -c "%u" $FILE ) "
    [ " $USERNAME1 = 1000" ] || chown 1000 $FILE
    [ " -r -w -x $FILE " ] || chmod +rwx $FILE
else
    mkdir ./MyWirelessCard
    FILE=./MyWirelessCard/fedora23_broadcom_wl_install.sh
    uname1=" $( stat -c "%u" $FILE ) "
    [ " $USERNAME1 = 1000" ] || chown 1000 $FILE
    [ " -r -w -x $FILE " ] || chmod +rwx $FILE
fi;

#Making wireless card installer run on boot
#echo "Making the wireless card install script run on boot"
#ln -s ./MyWirelessCard/fedora23_broadcom_wl_update.sh /etc/init.d/
#ln -s ./MyWirelessCard/fedora23_broadcom_wl_update.sh /etc/rc.d/

# Initial Update

echo "Preforming initial system update."
dnf -y update

#Exit

echo Script is finished
exit
```

I get:

> - ls /home/MyUserName Contents Of Folder
> - echo checking Root user checking Root user
> - '[' 1000 -ne 0 ']'
> - sudo su [sudo] password for MyUserName: 
>     ++ ping -c 1 74.125.21.14
>     ++ wc -l
> - TEST=6
> - '[' 6 -gt 5 ']'
> - sudo dnf install gcc kernel-devel binutils cpp glibc-devel glibc-headers isl kernel kernel-headers libmpc [sudo] password for
>     dcarr:
> - echo 'Starting the setup of your laptop'\''s wireless card.' Starting the setup of your laptop's wireless card.
> - '[' -d ./MyWirelessCard ']'
> - mkdir ./MyWirelessCard
> - FILE=./MyWirelessCard/fedora23_broadcom_wl_install.sh
>     ++ stat -c %u ./MyWirelessCard/fedora23_broadcom_wl_install.sh stat: cannot stat ‘./MyWirelessCard/fedora23_broadcom_wl_install.sh’: No
>     such file or directory
> - uname1='  '
> - '[' '  = 1000' ']'
> - '[' ' -r -w -x ./MyWirelessCard/fedora23_broadcom_wl_install.sh ' ']'
> - echo 'Preforming initial system update.' Preforming initial system update.
> - dnf -y update Error: This command has to be run under the root user.
> - echo Script is finished Script is finished
> - exit

I am at a loss any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the `sudo su` stuff is pointless. It's probably not good practice anyway, it's enough to complain about not running as root and exit. /edit: Ah, you're relying on authentication caching. That's even worse. :D

Comment: [Related reading](http://stackoverflow.com/q/59895/1025421)

Comment: Your quoting is wrong in many places. For example `[ " -r -w -x $FILE " ]` needs to be `[ -r "$FILE" ] && [ -w "$FILE" ] && [ -x "$FILE" ]`  -- your code will never be "false"

Comment: If you have to create that directory, then the $FILE will certainly not exist.

Comment: Interesting, but just out of curiosity, what is the difference? It does it's job for me, at least as far as I know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to actually change directories in your script. Typically:

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
```

Comment: I read somewhere that you can't use that if it contains the file, or is that about another command?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: When I use $PWD, it shows my user folder, not the script folder.

Comment: The script folder is `dirname "$0"`. After you cd there, $PWD will have the desired value.

Comment: Thanks it took a bit for me to put the peices together, and the related reading helped add to it that saves the last few remaining of my hairs left! :)